# Is there a way to make Dynamic Mapped tasks run end to end?

Tags: python, airflow

I have a dag that runs using dynamic mapping. However, for each task (contains sub tasks), it waits for all the sub-tasks to finish before triggering the next task. So my question is, is there a way to trigger upstream tasks for the already done subtask, this way the dag works in a first come first serve, while running the other subtasks in parallel.

The dag currently runs in an old fashioned way, so I haven't experimented with too many things to avoid breaking it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use partial and expand to generate dynamic tasks.
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.0/concepts/dynamic-task-mapping.html

```
@task()
def generate_tasks():
    # or [[1], [2], [3], [4]]
    return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 

@task()
def do_stuff(input: int):
    return input + 1

@task()
def gather(results: list[int]):
    print(results)

tasks = generate_tasks()
process = do_stuff.expand(input=tasks)
final = gather(results=process)

tasks >> process >> final
```

The above example will generate 5 tasks in parallel.

Comment: Ive done this already, but this doesnt print 1+1 first, it first returns the do_stuff in full before printing the first element. (even if you expand on the gather), so not quiet what im looking for, since thats what i have rn